# Can I apply gorrila glue on to a AAA battery to attach a wire to it?

Tags: batteries, radio

I am repairing a old CB radio I got at a yard sale and I'm powering it with 2 AAAs and a 9 volt. I have to attach a wire to all of the ports, and tape isn't very effective. I'm wondering if it it safe to use superglue on the metal surface of the battery (and keep in mind it's only 9 and 1.5 volts), and I know superglue is not a conductor.

Comment: https://www.mgchemicals.com/products/adhesives/electrically-conductive-adhesives/

Comment: Be as specific as possible. There are several "Gorilla" brand glues. Usually when talking about Gorilla glue, people are referring the type that requires water to be added, and the glue then expands. Are you only referring to "super glue", specifically "cyanoacrylate"?

Comment: Also, are you saying that you want to make electrical connections with glue, instead of solder? Or do you just want to hold the wire in place? I don't know what "attach a wire to all of the ports" means.

Comment: Finally, why are you using two different cell sizes and voltages (AA+9V)?

Comment: A 9v transistor radio battery is not up to this task.  If you want to run an automotive CB radio on battery, you likely need something like an emergency light gel cell, or perhaps 10 high current AA rechargeables.

Answer (score 4):

#### Just on battery connections:

It won't hurt the battery (other than dirtying the contacts) but it won't work very well. To make good electrical contact, you need *pressure* pushing the two metal surfaces together. Get an ordinary plastic battery holder with built-in springs for the 1.5V cells, and a snap for the 9V, and you will get good consistent electrical contact.

If you try to glue a wire on with nonconductive glue, it will most likely not work at all (if the glue forms a layer between the metals), be flaky, or be high-resistance (so that the voltage disappears when you actually put a load on it).

#### The rest of the problem:

You won't be able to run a radio — assuming it was intended to be installed in a car — from a standard 9V battery anyway. 9V batteries have high internal resistance and are intended for low-power applications, whereas the CB radio probably assumes a much higher capacity power source. If you want to make it turn on and receive, get a 12V power supply that plugs into the wall. Or use your car's "lighter socket" if you have a car — plug adapters to binding posts or wire can be found (be sure not to short it out or you will likely blow a fuse or worse!).

If you want to make the radio *transmit*, you need a power supply that is rated for significant current draw. Hopefully this is either on the back plate of the radio or in the owner's manual (which you can likely find on the internet); you need a power supply whose rating in (A)mperes is *at least as high* as the radio specifies.

Answer (score 1):

The glue will prevent the wires from getting electrical contact with the batteries. Your best bet would be getting battery holders either from scrapped electronics or from a store. Using tape or shrink tube would be the following one. Batteries with soldered connections do exist in the market but these involve special processes, heating up a battery with a soldering iron would be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean attach the wires to the metal contacts on the battery with glue that will not work.  If you cannot use battery holders or even solder then crinkle a bit of aluminum foil around the end of the wire and tape that tightly to the battery contact.  This is not an ideal solution but it will work temporarily.